# Downgrade iPhone 5s in iTunes recovery mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have tried to install a recovery file (.ipsw) for os version 10.3.3, to my iPhone 5s in recovery mode in iTunes. But i got this error in iTunes shown in the image.

Now my device is installed with IOS version 12.4.5, i need to downgrade to 10.3.3 or around 11 version.

I have tried with this website https://ipsw.me/ , its showing only valid os is 12.4.4 and 12.4.5

[image]

If have any idea to downgrade my device ping me.

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not directly related to programming, but you will find that Apple is no longer signing that version of iOS for your device so it cannot be installed.

Comment: @ElangovanE first downgrade your device to 12.4.4 if this will get you success then you will downgrade to lower version for example 12.4.4 to 12.3.3 then 12.2.2 then 12.1 vice versa. Because one of my friend told me that once.
may be it will help thanks.

Comment: @VipinPareek Actually tried that solution too, but no hope..